# Restrict Access (Meteor + React Router + Roles)

Tags: meteor, reactjs, react-router, meteor-react

I am trying to implement alanning Meteor-roles with react-router in my Meteor application. Everything is working fine except the fact I can't manage properly to restrict a route using alanning roles or `Meteor.user()`

**I tried with meteor-roles:**

I am trying to use the `onEnter={requireVerified}` on my route. This is the code:

```
const requireVerified = (nextState, replace) => {
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['verified'],'user_default')) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/account/verify',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },
        });
    }
};
```

**I tried with Meteor.user():**

```
const requireVerified = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (!Meteor.user().isverified == true) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/account/verify',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname },
    });
  }
};
```

So this is working when I am clicking on a route link, but when i manually refresh (F5), it does not work. After digging into it, i have found that `Meteor.user()` is not ready when i manually refresh the page.

> I know Meteor.userid() or Meteor.logginIn() are working, but i wanted
>   to verify not just that they are logged but if they are "verified" or
>   have a role.

I also tried to check inside the component with react, with `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillMount()`, in both cases it's the same, the manual fresh does not load `Meteor.user()` before the compenent is mounted.

So what is the best way to restrict components/routes with meteor/alaning roles + react router ? (I am using react-komposer inside TheMeteorChef's base)

Thank you.

Comment: id this 'verifier' requirement any way related to email verification?

Comment: no, I am verifying accounts with external api call (this app is working with a third party provider). In this example I am not showing exactly how is constructed the user object, but once the verification is completed on the external webiste i use a callback to update user object in meteor, adding a isverified = true in the database (no link with email verification provided by meteor)

Comment: @NOaMTL did you find a solution? I'm running into the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

*Note I have not tried it yet, it's only a suggestion*

One thing you could try is to use `componentWillReceiveProps` alongside createContainer from 'react-meteor-data' like that:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { user } = nextProps;
    if (user && !Roles.userIsInRole(user._id, ['verified'], 'user_default')) {
      browserHistory.push('/account/verify');
    }
    // If Meteor.user() is not ready, this will be skipped.
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  const user = Meteor.user() || null;
  return { user };
}, MyComponent);
```

To explain the flow, when the page is loaded, as you said Meteor.user() is not defined so you can't check the permissions. However, when Meteor.user() gets defined, this will trigger a refresh of the template, and the new props will be passed to `componentWillReceiveProps`. At this moment you can check if `user` has been defined and redirect if needed.

To  be really sure not to miss anything, I would actually put the verification in the `constructor()` as well (defining a function that takes the props as arguments and calling it in both `constructor()` and `componentWillReceiveProps()`).